# Checking connection/ communication

Tags: arduino-mega, communication

Can I ping or “hello world” an Arduino.
Background:  My son and I bought a 3-D printer kit.
[(EZ-3D)](https://www.phoenix3dprinter.com/)

We are having some issues talking with it.  (Well we can't talk at all.)  So we thought to upload the [firmware](https://ez3d.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/1000080546-uploading-firmware),

It’s an Arduino Mega 2560, and when we upload the Arduino times out… but it takes a minute or two.  Can I try some simpler program just to try and talk to the Arduino?

I’m almost a “virgin” Arduino user so be gentle.

Comment: Do you have an actual programmer or do you only have the on-board USB?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, Ahh.. I don't think we have a programmer, but I'm not sure.  (We downloaded the Arduino software... is that what you mean by programmer?)  I mostly an idiot in these types of things.

Comment: Something that can access the MCU at a low level, such as [this](http://www.fischl.de/usbasp/) or [this](http://www.atmel.com/tools/AVRISPMKII.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Adafruit has a good set of guides to getting started with arduino:
https://learn.adafruit.com/series/learn-arduino

The "[Blink](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-arduino-lesson-1-blink)" program is the equivalent of "hello world".

When testing you probably should disconnect the Arduino from the 3D printer.

Comment: Thanks Craig,  It's all built in so I can really remove anything.  (We (my son and I) did do some simple Arduino projects last year... talking to it was very easy.  Which surprised me at the time.

Comment: Blink is about the most basic Arduino program there is - it just flashes the on-board LED. But once you get that far you will have proven the Arduino software on your computer, the USB connection between your computer and the Arduino, and the basic functioning of the Arduino itself. It is a really useful step to take because you'll know that much of your system works and any troubles must be in the Arduino sketch, the Arduino itself, or the hardware connected to it. I do this whenever I update my Arduino software, connect to a new Arduino or to test a newly-built board.